# Formatting json files in pandas

Tags: json, pandas, excel, formatting

I have a set of somewhat messy json files and i need to formatt them to excel files with a specific structure.
I have found a way to unpack everything to a pandas dataframe, but my code so far does only carry int data types and not string.

This is the code I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

with open(r"PATH") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    #print(data)
    
df = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path =['passes'])
for col in df.columns:
    print(col)

df = df.groupby(['name', 'type']).apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x['cells'].tolist()[0], columns=['arguments.NOMINAL', 'id', 'onset', 'offset', '0', '1', '2', '3', 'Comments'])).reset_index([0,1]).reset_index(drop=True)

print(df)
```

Example json file:

{
"passes" : [ {
"name" : "SessionInfo",
"type" : "MATRIX",
"arguments" : {
"NOMINAL" : "ParticipantID",
"NOMINAL" : "Condition:CV/DG",
"NOMINAL" : "Task: Blocks/Blicket/Farm/PB/FPA/SF/FPB/WL"
},
"cells" : [ {
"id" : 1,
"onset" : "00:00:00:000",
"offset" : "00:00:00:000",
"values" : [ "002", "CV", "Blocks" ]
} ]
}, {
"name" : "PGesture",
"type" : "MATRIX",
"arguments" : {
"NOMINAL" : "P",
"NOMINAL" : "TYPE",
"NOMINAL" : "CATNUM",
"NOMINAL" : "LEVELS"
},
"cells" : [ {
"id" : 1,
"onset" : "00:00:01:326",
"offset" : "00:00:05:780",
"values" : [ "", "GRASP", "2", "TOWARD" ]
}, {
"id" : 2,
"onset" : "00:00:05:406",
"offset" : "00:00:15:946",
"values" : [ "", "SWIPE", "1", "ONE" ]
}, {
"id" : 3,
"onset" : "00:00:15:946",
"offset" : "00:00:24:378",
"values" : [ "", "TOY", "2", "NA" ]
}, {
"id" : 4,
"onset" : "00:00:29:478",
"offset" : "00:00:34:383",
"values" : [ "", "SWIPE", "1", "MULTI" ]
}, {
"id" : 5,
"onset" : "00:00:34:383",
"offset" : "00:00:37:060",
"values" : [ "", "REACH", "1", "OBJECT" ]
}, {
"id" : 6,
"onset" : "00:00:37:060",
"offset" : "00:00:45:732",
"values" : [ "", "MOVE", "1", "ONE" ]
}, {
"id" : 7,
"onset" : "00:00:40:732",
"offset" : "00:00:43:144",
"values" : [ "", "OTHER", "9", "ON" ]
}, {
"id" : 8,
"onset" : "00:00:44:608",
"offset" : "00:00:48:819",
"values" : [ "", "GRASP", "2", "TOWARD" ]
}, {
"id" : 9,
"onset" : "00:00:50:286",
"offset" : "00:01:12:324",
"values" : [ "", "SWIPE", "1", "ONE" ]
}, {
"id" : 10,
"onset" : "00:01:08:238",
"offset" : "00:01:09:722",
"values" : [ "", "GRASP", "2", "AWAY" ]
}, {
"id" : 11,
"onset" : "00:01:25:204",
"offset" : "00:01:26:715",
"values" : [ "", "GRASP", "2", "AWAY" ]
}, {
"id" : 12,
"onset" : "00:01:26:530",
"offset" : "00:01:29:834",
"values" : [ "", "MOVE", "1", "ONE" ]
} ]
}, {
"name" : "IGesture",
"type" : "MATRIX",
"arguments" : {
"NOMINAL" : "I",
"NOMINAL" : "TYPE",
"NOMINAL" : "CATNUM",
"NOMINAL" : "LEVELS"
},
"cells" : [ {
"id" : 1,
"onset" : "00:00:06:154",
"offset" : "00:00:18:553",
"values" : [ "", "SWIPE", "1", "ONE" ]
}, {
"id" : 2,
"onset" : "00:00:18:088",
"offset" : "00:00:40:800",
"values" : [ "", "TOY", "2", "NA" ]
}, {
"id" : 3,
"onset" : "00:00:49:096",
"offset" : "00:01:09:587",
"values" : [ "", "SWIPE", "1", "ONE" ]
}, {
"id" : 4,
"onset" : "00:01:09:904",
"offset" : "00:01:28:700",
"values" : [ "", "TOUCH", "1", "MULTI" ]
}, {
"id" : 5,
"onset" : "00:01:10:210",
"offset" : "00:01:14:094",
"values" : [ "", "ADJUST", "9", "SELF" ]
}, {
"id" : 6,
"onset" : "00:01:21:872",
"offset" : "00:01:23:748",
"values" : [ "", "REACH", "1", "OBJECT" ]
} ]
}, {
"name" : "Comments",
"type" : "MATRIX",
"arguments" : {
"NOMINAL" : "code01"
},
"cells" : [ {
"id" : 1,
"onset" : "00:00:40:732",
"offset" : "00:00:00:000",
"values" : [ "OTHER: moves the tablet closer to the Infant by nudging it with her elbow" ]
} ]
}, {
"name" : "Trial",
"type" : "MATRIX",
"arguments" : {
"NOMINAL" : "code01"
},
"cells" : [ ]
} ]
}

output:

name    type  arguments.NOMINAL  id         onset        offset  
0      Comments  MATRIX                NaN   1  00:00:00:000  00:00:00:000
1      IGesture  MATRIX                NaN   1  00:00:00:000  00:00:15:792
2      IGesture  MATRIX                NaN   2  00:00:11:050  00:00:14:258
3      IGesture  MATRIX                NaN   3  00:00:12:886  00:00:17:926
.
32     PGesture  MATRIX                NaN  15  00:01:24:660  00:01:30:300
33  SessionInfo  MATRIX                NaN   1  00:00:00:000  00:00:00:000

0   1   2   3  Comments
0  NaN NaN NaN NaN       NaN
1  NaN NaN NaN NaN       NaN
2  NaN NaN NaN NaN       NaN
3  NaN NaN NaN NaN       NaN
.
32 NaN NaN NaN NaN       NaN
33 NaN NaN NaN NaN       NaN

This is very close, only those NaN values should sometimes contain data...I don't know why they don't...

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize meta which should get you closer with the normalization:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(
    data=data,
    meta=[["passes", "name"], ["passes", "type"], ["passes", "arguments"]],
    record_path=["passes", "cells"]
)
df.columns = df.columns.str.split(".").str[-1]
print(df)
```